# How to implement multiple inheritance while using Flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, multiple-inheritance, flowtype

I'm developing a JS app and i would like to share code including my data classes between the front-end and back-end. I'm creating a base class with business logic, and then extending it with a database-connected version for the back-end, and AJAX-connected for the front-end. I have a function that takes the base class and returns a child class with standard DB functionality, and this class can then be extended with another class for additional specific methods. Basically `class DBUser extends DBWrapper(DBUserModel, BaseUser) {}`.

This code all works. Right now i'm trying to implement Flow in my codebase and it is complaining that my child class cannot implement the interface. There may be too much dynamic composition for a static code checker.

I'm using Sequelize for the database. Sequelize row instances contain all the properties of the row, but part of the problem is that the existing Flow typing doesn't seem to know that. So i should be able to pass a `DBUserModel` object in place of `UserData`, but Flow is not allowing it.

Here is a simplified MCVE of the Node.js back-end code:

```
/* @flow */

type BaseData = {
  id?: ?number
};

class BaseClass<TData: BaseData = BaseData> {
  id: ?number;

  constructor(data?: TData) {
    this._initFromData(data);
  }
  _initFromData(data?: TData) {
    if (!data) {
      this.id = null;
      return;
    }
    this.id = data.id;
  }
}

type UserData = {
  id?: ?number,
  name: string,
};

export interface IUser {
  id: ?number;
  name: string;

  _initFromData(data: UserData): void;

  save(): Promise<?IUser>;
  reload(): Promise<?IUser>;
}

class BaseUser extends BaseClass<UserData> implements IUser {
  id: ?number;
  name: string;

  _initFromData(data?: UserData={}) {
    if (!data.name) {
      throw new Error('User needs a name');
    }
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = data.name;
  }

  // these methods will be overridden in a child class
  async save() {}
  async reload() {}

  static async getById(id: number) {} // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
}

interface DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData> {
  _dbData: ?TModel;

  _initFromData(data: TModel & TData): void;

  save(): Promise<DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData>>;
  reload(): Promise<DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData>>;
}

// actually using Sequelize but mocking it here for a MCVE
class Model {
  update(data) {}
  reload() {}
  get(attr) {}
  static async create(data): Promise<Model> {return new this}
  static async findByPk(id): Promise<Model> {return new this}
}

function dbConnected<TModel: Model, TData: BaseData> (dbClass: Class<TModel>, baseClass: Class<BaseClass<TData>>) {
  return class extends baseClass implements DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData> {
    _dbData: ?TModel;

    constructor(data?: TData & TModel) {
      super(data);
      if (data instanceof dbClass) {
        this._dbData = data;
      }
    }
    _initFromData(data?: TData | TModel) {
      if (data instanceof dbClass) {
        super._initFromData(data.get({plain: true}));
      } else {
        super._initFromData(data);
      }
    }

    async save() {
      if (this._dbData) {
        await this._dbData.update(this);
      }
      if (this.id) {
        let data = (await dbClass.findByPk(this.id): TModel);
        this._dbData = data;
        if (this._dbData) {
          await this._dbData.update(this);
        }
      } else {
        let data: TModel = await dbClass.create(this);
        this._dbData = data;
        this.id = data.get({plain: true}).id;
      }
      return this;
    }

    async reload() {
      if (!this.id) {
        return this;
      }
      if (this._dbData) {
        await this._dbData.reload();
      }
      if (this.id) {
        let data = await dbClass.findByPk(this.id);
        this._dbData = data;
      }
      if (this._dbData) {
        this._initFromData(this._dbData);
      }
      return this;
    }

    static async getById(id: number) {
      const obj: ?TModel = await dbClass.findByPk(id);
      if (!obj) {
        throw new Error('not found');
      }
      return new this(obj);
    }
  }
}

const DBUserModel = Model; // actually it would be a subtype/subclass
class ConnectedUser extends dbConnected<DBUserModel, BaseUser>(DBUserModel, BaseUser) implements IUser, DBConnectedClass<DBUserModel, UserData> {
  // any user-specific DB code goes here
}
```

And here are the Flow errors:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ flow-test.js:138:1

Cannot implement IUser [1] with ConnectedUser because:
 • empty [2] is incompatible with UserData [3] in the first argument of property _initFromData.
 • property name is missing in <<anonymous class>> [4] but exists in IUser [5] in type argument R [6] of the return
   value of property reload.
 • property name is missing in <<anonymous class>> [4] but exists in IUser [7] in type argument R [6] of the return
   value of property save of type argument R [6] of the return value of property reload.
 • in the first argument of property _initFromData:
    • Either UserData [3] is incompatible with TData [8].
    • Or UserData [3] is incompatible with Model [9].
 • property name is missing in ConnectedUser [10] but exists in IUser [1].

           flow-test.js
       [3]  31│   _initFromData(data: UserData): void;
            32│
       [7]  33│   save(): Promise<?IUser>;
       [5]  34│   reload(): Promise<?IUser>;
              :
       [4]  75│   return class extends baseClass implements DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData> {
            76│     _dbData: ?TModel;
            77│
            78│     constructor(data?: TData & TModel) {
            79│       super(data);
            80│       if (data instanceof dbClass) {
            81│         this._dbData = data;
            82│       }
            83│     }
 [2][8][9]  84│     _initFromData(data?: TData | TModel) {
            85│       if (data instanceof dbClass) {
            86│         super._initFromData(data.get({plain: true}));
            87│       } else {
            88│         super._initFromData(data);
            89│       }
              :
           120│       }
           121│       if (this._dbData) {
           122│         this._initFromData(this._dbData);
           123│       }
           124│       return this;
           125│     }
           126│
           127│     static async getById(id: number) {
           128│       const obj: ?TModel = await dbClass.findByPk(id);
           129│       if (!obj) {
           130│         throw new Error('not found');
           131│       }
           132│       return new this(obj);
           133│     }
           134│   }
           135│ }
           136│
           137│ const DBUserModel = Model; // actually it would be a subtype/subclass
   [10][1] 138│ class ConnectedUser extends dbConnected<DBUserModel, BaseUser>(DBUserModel, BaseUser) implements IUser, DBConnectedClass<DBUserModel, UserData> {
           139│   // any user-specific DB code goes here
           140│ }
           141│

           /tmp/flow/flowlib_3f3cb1a7/core.js
       [6] 612│ declare class Promise<+R> {


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ flow-test.js:138:1

Cannot implement DBConnectedClass [1] with ConnectedUser because:
 • TModel [2] is incompatible with Model [3] in property _dbData.
 • TModel [4] is incompatible with Model [3] in type argument TModel [5] of type argument R [6] of the return value of
   property reload.
 • TData [7] is incompatible with UserData [8] in type argument TData [9] of type argument R [6] of the return value
   of property reload.
 • property name is missing in BaseData [7] but exists in UserData [8] in type argument TData [9] of type argument
   R [6] of the return value of property reload.
 • in the first argument of property _initFromData:
    • Either Model [3] is incompatible with TData [10].
    • Or UserData [8] is incompatible with TData [10].
    • Or Model [3] is incompatible with TModel [11].
    • Or UserData [8] is incompatible with TModel [11].

           flow-test.js
    [5][9]  56│ interface DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData> {
              :
    [4][7]  75│   return class extends baseClass implements DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData> {
       [2]  76│     _dbData: ?TModel;
              :
  [10][11]  84│     _initFromData(data?: TData | TModel) {
              :
           135│ }
           136│
           137│ const DBUserModel = Model; // actually it would be a subtype/subclass
 [1][3][8] 138│ class ConnectedUser extends dbConnected<DBUserModel, BaseUser>(DBUserModel, BaseUser) implements IUser, DBConnectedClass<DBUserModel, UserData> {
           139│   // any user-specific DB code goes here
           140│ }
           141│

           /tmp/flow/flowlib_3f3cb1a7/core.js
       [6] 612│ declare class Promise<+R> {


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ flow-test.js:138:77

Cannot call dbConnected with BaseUser bound to baseClass because UserData [1] is incompatible with BaseUser [2] in type
argument TData [3].

 [3]   7│ class BaseClass<TData: BaseData = BaseData> {
        :
 [1]  37│ class BaseUser extends BaseClass<UserData> implements IUser {
        :
     135│ }
     136│
     137│ const DBUserModel = Model; // actually it would be a subtype/subclass
 [2] 138│ class ConnectedUser extends dbConnected<DBUserModel, BaseUser>(DBUserModel, BaseUser) implements IUser, DBConnectedClass<DBUserModel, UserData> {
     139│   // any user-specific DB code goes here
     140│ }
     141│
```

How can i teach Flow what my code is doing, or else refactor the code a little to better handle static checking?

Comment: Use model class (e.g.) user which contains only fields and no methods (however simplest is best so your model class name has been similar to table name, and fields same as column names). (of course sometaime you can add some methods). Then create SERVICE which GET/POST/PUT/DELETE models (using Restful API (google it)).

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I'm not sure how that's relevant. This is the part of the code that needs to connect with the database directly, not over a REST API. And the user class does contain as properties only fields from the database. As i said, the code itself works, i need with the Flow typing for it.

Comment: maybe I miss understand - probably you using node.js ?

Comment: Yes, i'm using Node. Just added the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by changing the way i do the database connecting. Instead of deriving from a base class, i use a mixin pattern to modify the child class directly. `class DBUser extends User {}; dbMixin(DBUserModel, DBUser);`

I ran into an issue with Flow not allowing me to overwrite methods on the prototype, but i was able to get around it by casting first to `any`, and then fixing the typecast of `this` inside the function. A bit hacky but it must be done.

```
/* @flow */

type BaseData = {
  id?: ?number
};

class BaseClass<TData: BaseData = BaseData> {
  id: ?number;

  constructor(data?: TData) {
    this._initFromData(data);
  }
  _initFromData(data?: TData) {
    if (!data) {
      this.id = null;
      return;
    }
    this.id = data.id;
  }

  static async getById(id) {}
}

type UserData = BaseData & {
  name: string,
};

export interface IUser {
  id: ?number;
  name: string;

  _initFromData(data: UserData): void;

  save(): Promise<?IUser>;
  reload(): Promise<?IUser>;
}

class BaseUser extends BaseClass<UserData> implements IUser {
  id: ?number;
  name: string;

  _initFromData(data?: UserData={}) {
    if (!data.name) {
      throw new Error('User needs a name');
    }
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = data.name;
  }

  // these methods will be overridden in a child class
  async save() {}
  async reload() {}

  static async getById(id: number) {} // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
}

interface DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData> {
  id?: ?number;
  _dbData: ?TModel;

  constructor(data: TModel | TData): void;

  _initFromData(data: TModel | TData): void;

  save(): Promise<void>;
  reload(): Promise<void>;
}

// actually using Sequelize but mocking it here for a MCVE
class Model {
  id: ?number;
  name: string;

  update(data) {}
  reload() {}
  get(attr) {}
  static async create(data): Promise<Model> {return new this}
  static async findByPk(id): Promise<Model> {return new this}
}

function dbConnectedMixin<TModel: Model, TData: BaseData> (dbClass: Class<TModel>, baseClass: Class<DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData>>) {
  const _initFromData = baseClass.prototype._initFromData;
  (baseClass: any).prototype._initFromData = function(data?: TData | TModel) {
    const self = (this: DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData>);
    if (data instanceof dbClass) {
      self._dbData = data;
    }
    _initFromData.call(self, data);
  };

  // const save = baseClass.prototype.save;
  (baseClass: any).prototype.save = async function() {
    const self = (this: DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData>);
    if (self._dbData) {
      await self._dbData.update(self);
    }
    if (self.id) {
      let data = (await dbClass.findByPk(self.id): TModel);
      self._dbData = data;
      if (self._dbData) {
        await self._dbData.update(self);
      }
    } else {
      let data: TModel = await dbClass.create(self);
      self._dbData = data;
      self.id = data.get({plain: true}).id;
    }
  };

  // const reload = baseClass.prototype.reload;
  (baseClass: any).prototype.reload = async function() {
    const self = (this: DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData>);
    if (!self.id) {
      return;
    }
    if (self._dbData) {
      await self._dbData.reload();
    }
    if (self.id) {
      let data = await dbClass.findByPk(self.id);
      self._dbData = data;
    }
    if (self._dbData) {
      self._initFromData(self._dbData);
    }
  };

  (baseClass: any).getById = async function(id: number) {
    const self = (this: Class<DBConnectedClass<TModel, TData>>);
    const obj: ?TModel = await dbClass.findByPk(id);
    if (!obj) {
      throw new Error('not found');
    }
    return new self(obj);
  };
}

const DBUserModel = Model; // actually it would be a subtype/subclass
class ConnectedUser extends BaseUser implements IUser, DBConnectedClass<DBUserModel, UserData> {
  _dbData: ?DBUserModel;

  // any user-specific DB code goes here
}
dbConnectedMixin<DBUserModel, UserData>(DBUserModel, ConnectedUser);
```